# "Result of function call is ignored": CodeWarrior. Why is it ignored?

Tags: c, extern, microprocessors

Here's a pseudo-code(ish) that I'm trying to build.

This is the interrupt function. When switch 2 is pressed, the potval = 1. When switch 3 is pressed, potval = 2. Every time the switch is pressed, the potval is updated.

```
void interruptJ_function (void){ //if i change to int interruptJ_function, it says that it was expecting a void function

  if(Pim.pifj.byte & 0x01)  {   //switch2 is pressed

    potval = 1;
    
    Pim.pifj.byte |= 0x01;    //clear interrupt bit
    //return potval;   //doing this says the result is returned in void-result-function
    
  } 
  
  else if(Pim.pifj.byte & 0x02)  { //switch 3 is pressed
    potval = 2;

    Pim.pifj.byte |= 0x02;   //clear interrupt bit
    //return potval;
  }
  
  //return potval;
  
}
```

Here's the main.c.

```
int potval;
unsigned int i;


void main ()
{
  adt(potval);   //Warning: Result of function call is ignored

  for (;;); //recurring loop until interrupt initiated
}

int adt(int potval, unsigned int i) {
  
  if(potval == 1){ 
    //for (;;){     
    while(potval==1){ //breaks when potval =2
      
      i= Atd0.atddr[0].d10;     //ATD bits
     
      light7segment(i); // ATD changes number on 7segment display
    
        m_delay(50);
    }
 } 
  
  else if (potval == 2){
    light7segment(10); //ATD turns off 7segment display
    
  } 

}
```

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/7544-game-center-for-ios-building-a-turn-based-game

Comment: `However, its keep saying "result of function call is ignored" on CodeWarrior.` How is it related to the extern int variable and sharing it? Are you asking some XY question?

Comment: @KamilCuk what is an XY question?

Comment: Did you try googling, literally "XY question"? https://www.google.com/search?q=XY+question

Comment: @KamilCuk ah... I suppose I was asking an xy question. Would changing the title to ""result of function call is ignored" on CodeWarrior" be a better question title?

Comment: Surely CodeWarrior associates the diagnostic with a particular source line?

Comment: And still: what does the diagnostic have to do with sharing variables?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you have to flag the interrupt as an interrupt or the MCU will quickly go haywire. This is usually done with `#pragma TRAP_PROC`. If you don't do this, then the compiler will generate RTS instructions instead of RTI instructions. Which might cause the PC to jump into the woods instead of returning from the interrupt.

Comment: Change `adt` return type to `void`. You don't use it AND there is no `return` in function.

Answer (score 1):

Codewarrior gives this warning when you call a function with a return value but ignore checking that return value. As you do here:

```
adt(potval);
```

Normally the solution would be `(void) adt(potval);`.

Not in this case though, because the reason is a much more severe bug, namely that the function `int adt(int potval, unsigned int i)` doesn't `return` a value. On most Codewarrior target systems, it means that the caller code will grab some random value out of an accumulator, then run off into the woods. This bug could have be avoided if you had paid attention when the compiler said "return expected" in a different warning.

Comment: I see.. would simply moving everything in the adt function to the main function fix the bug?

Comment: @JoshuaPark Not much of your code makes any sense I'm afraid. You also have the wrong amount of parameters. And why do you have 2 global variables named the same as the parameters. And so on. I'd step away from this and start with a good C programming book. Codewarrior and old Freescale MCUs isn't the friendliest environment for learning.